# Is there a possibility of giving a name to a graph and edit it aferwards?

Tags: python, matplotlib, draw

I have two pieces of code i am trying to connect,in the first one, i am creating an empty graph and in the secondone i want to plot to this graph.

The second function is called inside a loop, to continously update the graph.

Here is the code creating the empty plot:

```
class CreateGraph():

    def construct(self):
        xar=[]
        yar=[]
        graph=plt.plot(xar,yar)[0]
        plt.ion()
        plt.axis([0,1,0,50])
        plt.ylabel("Sentiment")
        plt.xlabel("Number of Tweets")
        plt.show()
        plt.pause(0.001)

        return graph
```

Here is the code updatig the plot above:

```
class UpdateGraph():

    def __init__(self,graph):
        self.xar=[]
        self.yar=[]

    def update_plot(self):
        graph_data=open("twitter-out.txt", "r")
        graph_data=list(graph_data)
        graph_data=graph_data[0].split(",")
        x=0
        y=0
        for l in graph_data:
            x+=1
            y=float(l)
            self.xar.append(x)
            self.yar.append(y)

        graph.set_xdata(self.xar)
        graph.set_ydata(self.yar)
        print(graph)  
        graph.draw()
        graph.pause(0.001)
```

Currently i am getting the following error:

```
Failed:  draw_wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'renderer'
```

I understand this has something to do with figures and how to plot them, but cant pinpoint my error.

Comment: maybe `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and then instead of `plt.plot`, `plt.blablabla` use `ax.plot` etc and instead of returning `graph` return `fig, ax`?

Comment: have you found it ? because it would be nice if ou could tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: You need `plt.draw()` and `plt.pause()` instead of `graph.draw()` and `graph.pause()`.